# SSIS ScriptTask Issue

Tags: c#, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis-2008

I am building a SSIS package in Sql Server 2008R2.  I need to add a Script Task to this package but I have run into a strange issue.  I create the Script Task and select edit script.  I can see all the files I need are there and can edit the scripttask.cs file with no issue.  Once I save then close this task and try and reopen it the ScriptTask.cs is missing as well as the files listed under properties. I have asked a couple people in the office and no one here has ever had this issue.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: did you edit the script file while your package was running or when faced an runtime error before stopping its execution?

Comment: No.  I have started from scratch with a package that only has a script task in it.  Nothing is running.   It is really strange.

Comment: I recall this happening once a few years ago with 2008 R2.  But it only happened once.  After restoring the source files, I ran the package again it worked and continued to work.  Does this continue to happen each time you run the SSIS package?  If so, something could be corrupted.  Try deleting and recreating the Script Task and try just running the Script Task only and nothing after it.

Comment: After playing with it for a while I decided something is in fact corrupted on my machine.  I will have to reinstall SQL and see if that works.